# How can I specify that some command line arguments are mandatory in Python?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm writing a program in Python that accepts command line arguments.  I am parsing them with `getopt` (though my choice of `getopt` is no Catholic marriage.  I'm more than willing to use any other library).  Is there any way to specify that certain arguments *must* be given, or do I have to manually make sure that all the arguments were given?

**Edit:** I changed all instances of *option* to *argument* in response to public outcry.  Let it not be said that I am not responsive to people who help me :-)

Comment: +1 for Catholic marriage metaphor. It made me smile.

Comment: "mandatory option" is contradictory.  You mean "arguments".  And -- it appears -- you mean "arguments" with the syntax of "options".  The options/arguments is nicely defined here: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#terminology and here: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to do it yourself. I.e.

```
found_f = False
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "ho:v", ["help", "output="])
except getopt.GetoptError, err:
    print str(err)
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)
for o, a in opts:
    if o == '-f':
      process_f()
      found_f = True
    elif ...
if not found_f:
    print "-f was not given"
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: I was looking for a way not to do it myself, but if there is none, then I guess this is the answer.

Answer (score 9):

As for me I prefer using [optparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), it is quite powerful, for exapmle it can automatically generate -h message by given options:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="filename",
                  help="write report to FILE", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet",
                  action="store_false", dest="verbose", default=True,
                  help="don't print status messages to stdout")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

You should manually check if all arguments were given:

```
if len(args) != 1:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
```

Making options mandatory seems to be quite strange for me - they are called **options** not without any sense...

Comment: If the value *must* be given, but you have the option of which value to give, then it's still an option, isn't it?  What would you call it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the purpose of this yet. Can you give a me some example, e.g. describing cli input? Not essential the exact problem you are solving, just any...

Comment: sure.  I'm writing a script that works on a file.  If you don't specify a filename, the script won't know what to work on, so the filename is mandatory.

Comment: So, in terms of optparse this is arguments ('args' in the code above), and unfortunatelly, as I wrote you should check them manually...

Answer (score 0):

From argparse library, you can use required=True in option

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Help msg", 
                                 formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument("-i", "--intput",  help="image input",  required=True)
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output",  help="image output", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", help="version"                    )
```

and then compile

```
> main.py -h
Help msg
optional arguments:
-h, --help     show this help message and exit
-i, --input    image input
-o, --output   image output
-v, --version  version

> main.py
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--intput, -o/--output
```

and you have it, -i and -o options are mandatory.

visit this [website](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-command-line-arguments-with-argparse-6824c30ab1c3), he explain it well.